# Date String to Time tuple

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to pass a string into as function and need to convert it into a time tuple:

```
def  sim(startdate, enddate):
    # need to convert the date from string to integer time tuple:
    dt_start = dt.date(startdate)
    print 'Start Date: ', dt_start

    dt_end = dt.date(enddate)
    print 'End Date: ', dt_end

# in String format
sim('Jan 1, 2011', 'Dec 31, 2011')

# in interger in string format
sim('2011,1,1', '2011,12,31')
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a integer time tuple? Including the expected output would help

Comment: dt.date(2011,1,1) throws an error if not in the 2011,1,1 format, so needs to be converted somehow.

Comment: Why don't you use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: import datetime as dt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Have a time format defined for both of your formats and use them accordingly. This is what I mean:

```
import datetime as dt

def  sim(startdate, enddate):
    time_format_one = "%b %d, %Y"
    time_format_two = "%Y,%m,%d"

    try:
        dt_start = dt.datetime.strptime(startdate, time_format_one)
        dt_end = dt.datetime.strptime(enddate, time_format_one)
    except ValueError:
        dt_start = dt.datetime.strptime(startdate, time_format_two)
        dt_end = dt.datetime.strptime(enddate, time_format_two)

    print 'Start Date: ', dt_start.date()
    print 'End Date: ', dt_end.date()

# in String format
sim('Jan 1, 2011', 'Dec 31, 2011')

# in interger in string format
sim('2011,1,1', '2011,12,31')
```

prints:

```
Start Date:  2011-01-01
End Date:  2011-12-31
Start Date:  2011-01-01
End Date:  2011-12-31
```

You could use [`timetuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple) on `dt_start` and `dt_end` if you need time tuple.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to convert date ('Jan 1, 2011', 'Dec 31, 2011') and ('2011,1,1', '2011,12,31') into timetuple

```
 from datetime import datetime
 date_str = "Jan 1, 2011"
 fmt = "%b %d, %Y"

 # Construct a datetime object
 date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt)

 # Convert it to any string format you want
 new_fmt = "%Y, %m, %d"
 print date_obj.strftime(new_fmt)
 # Prints'2011, 01, 01'

 # If you want python timetuple then
 t_tuple = date_obj.timetuple()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably trying to do is the following:

```
import datetime as dt

year,month,day = map(int, '2011,1,1'.split(','))
dt_start = dt.date(year,month,day)
print dt_start # prints 2011-01-01
```

The error is because of the use of a string `'2011,1,1'` instead of integers: `2011,1,1` as an input to: `datetime.date()`